# How to maintain decimal precision in calculations

Tags: c#, math, decimal

I need to sum 2 decimal values together, then divide by 2 and convert to string.

My calculation currently is trimming to 2 decimal places, but I want to keep as many decimals as I can.

```
city.Latitude = ( (lat.North + lat.South) / 2 ).ToString();
```

the values for lat.North and lat.South are like: 55.32342322

Comment: Just out of curiosity: lat.North + lat.South / 2 ? What are you "trying" to calculate ?

Comment: Maybe your city.Latitude should be of type decimal and not of type string. Than everything is fine.

Comment: Trying to get the exact geo location, not a square area. is that a wrong way to do it?  google maps returns:  <LatLonBox north="34.1377559" south="34.0642330" east="-118.3896720" west="-118.4467160" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here:

**Standard Numeric Format Strings**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

You probably want to specify a "G" or "F" format specifier in [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx) of the `ToString()` method.

Comment: He also likely wants to make `city.Latitude` a decimal, since it does store decimal values and not string values.